# Passing a double to a method that accepts T

Tags: java, generics, javafx, generic-programming

**Question**

I am trying to pass a double to a method that accepts T. That method (In this case. I plan to add the cases for String, int, etc.) requires the item passed to be a double or else it will throw an error.

Basically, I want to pass a double to `commitEdit(T)`.

**Background**

I understand I am being very vague so I'll try to elaborate. I am attempting to create a class that extends `TableCell<S,T>` such that I can use it generically. I have no experience with `<S,T>` parameters. The method I am trying to call is `commitEdit(T)` which up until now I have been creating a new class that extends `TableCell<CustomRowObject, Double>` and everything has been working fine because `commitEdit(Double)` is easy enough to call.

The problem is that every time I want to make a new table, I have to make a new cell class and I would rather create a generic cell that handles the casting of the value from an Object to Double, String, Integer, etc, and passes it to `commitEdit(T)`.

In all my years of programming i have always tried to avoid generic arguments but now I believe it is a good time to learn.

**Code**

Here's an example of the wrapper for `commitEdit(T)` that I've come up with so far(Doesnt work)

```
    public static class EditingCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

        public EditingCell() {
        }

        public void commit(Object val) {
            if(val instanceof Double) {
                commitEdit((Double) val);
            } else if(val instanceof String) {
                commitEdit((String) val);
            }
        }
    }
```

`The method commitEdit(T) in the type TableCell<S,T> is not applicable for the arguments (double)`

**Im Dumb**

As in this specific case, all I had to do was cast to T as such `commitEdit( (T) val)`.

Comment: What have you actually tried? It works for me…

Comment: I just added the code as you replied, sorry

Comment: Sorry, when instanceof tells you that your object is a Double, why do you convert the Double to String, to then parse it to get a Double? Ever heard of casting?

Comment: Good point. However this method still doesn't accept a casted value. I think I am attempting to do something that I'd need more information on how `commitEdit()` actualyl works though. Sorry

Comment: If you pass a `double` to a method which expects an `Object` (or a `T`, which is erased to `Object`), it would be auto-boxed to `Double`.

Comment: turns out I over-complicated it and all I had to do was cast the value to T..

Comment: @Duck even that sounds over-complicated. Why not just `public void commit(T val)`? (Or have you omitted the `@Override`?)

Comment: If I use `public void commit(T val)` I get errors that I cant pass a double to the function. However `public void commit(Object val)` seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't really need to cast if you use generics: that's kind of the point. Shouldn't you just define `commit` as `public void commit(T val) { ... }`? (Though it's not really clear what your `commit` method provides that is different to `commitEdit` anyway.)

Comment: the more that I get into this, the more I realize it provides absolutely nothing compared to `commitEdit`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
@Test
public void testDoubleGeneric()
{
    commitEdit(3.1514D);
}

private <T> void commitEdit(final T value)
{
    if (!(value instanceof Double))
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

However I'd argue, that your approach to use generics is not the right approach for your problem. Whenever you have to use `instanceof`, generics are not the solution. Consider method overloading instead.

```
public void commit(Double d) ...

public void commit(String str) ...
```

Comment: This is a good answer however my specific solution didn't really pertain to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example extends TableCell {

    public <T> void commit(T value) {
        if(arg instanceof Double) {
            // do whatever
        } else if(arg instanceof String) {
            // do something else
        }
    }
}
```